# What is webservices-rt.jar? Is it related to Metro?

Tags: java, web-services, microsoft-metro

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I'm really confused and cannot get a clear idea about it since I'm very new in java web service.

I have a project which exposes some web service APIs, I was told that this project uses Metro, but I don't see Metro related jar like jaxws-rt.jar, instead, I see webservices-rt.jar.

I'm wondering to know what webservices-rt.jar is, and where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the main Metro jar, you can verify this searching the jar in maven central: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/webservices-rt/2.0

Comment: thank you, what is the relation between Metro jaxws-rt.jar and this webservices-rt.jar, are they same?

Comment: jaxws-rt is the simpler Oracle *reference implementation* for webservices, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798351/jax-ws-implementation-included-with-java

Comment: webservices-rt.jar can only be found in maven repository? I'm not able to find it in metro official site.

Comment: It's not even in the full distribution zip? https://metro.java.net/2.3.1/ Where did you get it? It was the copy included in glassfish or something like that? Btw, at least now you know what it is, question answered! :D

Comment: Thank you, sure, I'll select this as a answer.