# What is the purpose of CXF servlet

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf

I was going through a demo project setup for Restful webservice using Apache CXF, where I happened to come by a piece of code inside web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I did not really understand the use of a servlet class in this web.xml. I googled for `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` and found:

> The CXFServlet class, which is defined by Apache CXF, is generated and
>   registered to handle incoming requests.

Now, I really do not understand what that line means

1. Does this servlet pose as a front-controller, like in Spring MVC flow?
2. What is the actual purpose of using this servlet class?
3. How does CXF use Spring to provide XML configuration of services defined in the project?
4. Does `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` serve the same purpose in Jersey Implementation as `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` with Apache CXF?

Help me clarify these questions.

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per question, asking multiple questions make your question too broad, and make it hard to give targeted and complete answers. Especially your points 3 and 4 should really be separate questions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Will keep in my mind from next time onwards...Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JAX-RS specification is built on top of the Servlet specification. Each implementation should have a Servlet as an entry point to the application. When a request comes in, it gets processed by that Servlet. `CXFServlet` is CXF's implementation of that entry point Servlet.

> Does this servlet pose as a front-controller, like in Spring MVC flow?

Pretty much. It's analogous to Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet`

> What is the actual purpose of using this servlet class?

As mentioned above, it's the entry point to the JAX-RS (CXF) application.

> How does CXF use Spring to provide XML configuration of services defined in the project?

It uses Spring to wire up components; connect all of them together. But [it's not required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/689902/2587435) ([see also](https://www.javatips.net/blog/cxf-rest-without-spring)).

> Does `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` serve the same purpose in Jersey Implementation as `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` with Apache CXF?

Pretty much.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSamsotha... I guess I can start with these information to dig up more on the same. It really helped me to understand a bit easily. Though I would like to ask one more question here. Can you please elaborate a little the sentence **JAX-RS specification is built on top of the Servlet specification**. That would help me.

Comment: [JAX-RS  is a specification](http://download.oracle.com/javaee-archive/jax-rs-spec.java.net/jsr339-experts/att-3593/spec.pdf). In this document, they specify that a JAX-RS application should be run as a servlet application in a servlet container.